# Unity MT grab Handles plugin disappeared!

Tags: unity, compiz, plugins, grab-handles

I discovered it just today, and I don't know how long it had gone.
in brief, if I open ccsm, under uncategorized plugins, I can't find Unity Grab Handles plugin and I'm pretty sure it was at its place at first, because I configured it.

I'm running 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it back, because I was using unity-5.X that does not include the plugin.
Now it was restored.